# Carregar dados no scrollview - Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

Estou com algum erro no meu código e não estou encontrando o erro...
Eu criei duas requisições a uma api, uma para buscar os dados pessoais do usuário e outra para buscar a estada dele no hotel, oque ocorre é que quando eu acesso o aplicativo pela primeira vez, ele carrega as informações do perfil, porém os dados da estada(reserva) não carrega no scrollview, se eu clico em sair e logo novamente, ele carrega os dados, é como se em alguns momento não fosse executado o bloco de código dessa segunda requisição, segue exemplo de como fica abaixo, como fazer a requisição do perfil e logo depois fazer a outra requisição para que apresente na tela as duas? ou melhor, como corrigir este erro?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue código abaixo:

```
package com.example.hotelprimeapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.hotelprimeapp.model.Estada;
import com.example.hotelprimeapp.model.Pessoa;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView resultTextProfile;
    private TextView resultTextReserva;
    private JsonPlaceHolderApi JsonPlaceHolderApi;
    private JsonPlaceHolderApi JsonPlaceHolderApi2;
    private Button btnLogout;

    public static String cpf_cli = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        String url = "http://000.00.00.000:00000/api/";
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        JsonPlaceHolderApi = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);
        resultTextProfile = findViewById(R.id.listProfile);
        resultTextReserva = findViewById(R.id.listStay);
        btnLogout = findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);

        int cod_psoa = LoginActivity.cod_psoa;
        Call<Pessoa> call = JsonPlaceHolderApi.getPessoas(cod_psoa);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Pessoa>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Pessoa> call, Response<Pessoa> response) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    resultTextProfile.setText("Code: " + response.code());
                    return;
                }

                Pessoa pessoas = response.body();

                String content = "";
                content += "Nome: " + pessoas.getNome() + " " + pessoas.getSobrenome() + "\n";
                content += "Cpf: " + pessoas.getCpf() + "\n";
                content += "E-mail: " + pessoas.getEmail() + "\n";
                content += "Nasc: " + pessoas.getData_nasc().substring(0, 10) + "\n";
                cpf_cli = pessoas.getCpf();
                resultTextProfile.append(content);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Pessoa> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                resultTextProfile.setText(t.getMessage());
            }
        });

        Call<List<Estada>> callEst = JsonPlaceHolderApi.getEstadas();
        callEst.enqueue(new Callback<List<Estada>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Estada>> callEst, Response<List<Estada>> response) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    resultTextReserva.setText("Code: " + response.code());
                    return;
                }

                List<Estada> estadas = response.body();
                for (Estada estada : estadas) {

                    if (estada.getCpf_clnt().equals(ProfileActivity.cpf_cli)) {
                        String situacao = estada.getSituacao();
                        switch (situacao) {
                            case "A":
                                situacao = "<font color=#0b6314><b>ATIVA</b></font>";
                                break;
                            case "F":
                                situacao = "<font color=#8c0f0f><b>FINALIZADA</b></font>";
                                break;
                        }
                        String content = "";
                        resultTextReserva.append("");
                        content += "Acomodação: " + "<font>" + estada.getTipo_acmd() + "</font> <br>";
                        content += "Entrada: " + "<font>" + estada.getDtahra_chda().substring(0, 10) + "</font> <br>";
                        content += "Saída: " + "<font>" + estada.getDtahra_sida().substring(0, 10) + "</font> <br>";
                        content += "Pessoas: " + "<font>" + estada.getQtd_psoa() + "</font> <br>";
                        content += "Situação: " + "<font>" + situacao + "</font> <br>";
                        content += "<font>" + "______________________________________________" + "</font> <br>";
                        resultTextReserva.append(Html.fromHtml(content, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));

                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<List<Estada>> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                resultTextReserva.setText(t.getMessage());
            }
        });

        btnLogout.setOnClickListener(
                view -> {
                    finish();
                    Intent loginpage = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(loginpage);
                });
    }
}
```

---

Atualização 09/11/21 11:19

Pessoal, acredito que o problema esteja na minha conversão do content para html, pois ao passar somente o content no **resultTextReserva** ele carrega normalmente, não sei oque está errado nessa conversão...

---

Atualização 09/11/21 13:43

Percebi que ao dividir a tela do celular em 2 e voltar ao normal o scroll view é carregado normalmente...

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver utilizando o invalidate e requestLayout.

scrollViewReserva.invalidate();
scrollViewReserva.requestLayout();

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).